# Webmin slave DNS

Tags: ubuntu, bind, cluster, slave

I setup slave DNS server for my master, I configured everything, all domains was transfered to the slave server, I can add new domain, edit existing domain, but in the logs I've got problems.

There is thousands of this logs :

```
zone domain.com/IN: refresh: could not set file modification time of '/var/lib/bind/domain.com.hosts': permission denied
```

How I can solve this problem ? Sometimes I have to add more then one A record to transfer the domain to slave server.

Answer (score 2):

What are the permissions of /var/lib/bind and the hosts files within it? The likely problem is the files are owned by root:root, but need to be owned by bind:bind or named:named or similar. Check to see what user owns the BIND process, and make sure those files are owned by that user. BIND drops privileges after starting and claiming its ports, and so if the files are owned by root, it wouldn't be able to alter them.

You can change file ownership with the command:

```
# chown bind:bind /var/lib/bind/domain.com.hosts
```